# User is getting logged out when they tried to change the password from my accounts section

Tags: customer-account, magento2.3.4, magento-upgrade

I'm facing a peculiar issue with Magento2.3.4-p2 (upgraded from 2.2.6). When the user changes the password from my accounts section, the user is getting logged out.I verified till the redirect to /customer/account in EditPost.php, $this->session->isLoggedIn is true.

Comment: I can confirm the same still happens in 2.3.5-p1

Comment: Thanks, @xpoback :)

Answer (score 4):

This is the expected behavior from 2.3.4-p2. We can see this has a new update from 2.3.5 release notes
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-5-open-source.html#customer

Comment: Thanks, now I don't have to worry I broke something :)